# Why do I get a repeated array with shuffle method

Tags: python

I want to get 3 permutations of the same array and store them in a list. To do this I was trying to use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = []
for i in range (0,2):
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    x = x + [a]
```

When running this code the array gets shuffled. However, I get:

```
x = [[5,4,2,3,1],[5,4,2,3,1]]
```

Why do I get the same array repeated?

Comment: You didn't assign ``np.random.shuffle(a)`` to any variable

Comment: @Karina `np.random.shuffle()` shuffles in place and does not return anything.

Comment: You put `a` into your list `x` multiple times. So your `x` just contains `a` multiple times.

Comment: @bereal oh okay, my bad. Not familiar with that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep adding the same `a` instance, so you see it in every box of the `x` array, you may copy it

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = []
for i in range(3):
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    x.append(list(a))
```

---

For not inplace shuffle, `random.sample` can be used but it is less performant

```
from random import sample

x = []
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(3):
    x.append(sample(a, k=len(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A list in Python is always by reference (if you know C or C++, think of it as a pointer).
This concept can be understood by the following demo

```py
a = []
b = a
a.append(1)
print(b) # [1]
```

Since `random.shuffle` shuffles the list in-place, to get a different list you need to make a copy of it. Consider the following code

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = []
for i in range (2):
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    x.append(a[:])
```

Here `[:]` is a slice operator without any index, which creates a copy of the list. I would also note that the use of `np` is unnecessary here, as the same thing can be achieved using `random.shuffle` from the standard library.